# Request parameters are dropped in Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, jersey

Client code:

```
    FormDataBodyPart f = new FormDataBodyPart(...);
    FormDataBodyPart f2 = new FormDataBodyPart(...);
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    multiPart.bodyPart(f);
    multiPart.bodyPart(f2);

    //Execute Call
    WebResource wr = resource().path(Url.X);
    wr = wr.queryParam("subjectId", "value_something");
    ClientResponse response = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

Server code:

```
String id = req.getParameter("subjectId");
```

req is HttpServletRequest - injected by spring

```
@Context
protected HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
```

Problem: on some of the environments the `id` parameter retrieved is null. In the filter we print the while request parameters map to log in it is just empty.
We believe the problem is on server side since the same client executed vs. different environments gives different result.
On some servers the parameter is always empty, from all clients, and on other environments the parameter is always there, from all clients.
So... it looks like the problem on the Tomcat side, but... where?

Update: result from wireshark on server:

```
[Malformed Packet: MIME multipart]
Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)
Message: Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)
```

on some servers despite the error - the parameter is there and on others the param is missing.

**Update**: the logged request by AccessLogValve contains the parameter
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2012:03:04:58 -0800] "POST /api/get-retrieve?**x=y** HTTP/1.1" 200 16
So, probably the problem is somewhere in the Tomcat throwing out those params...

Comment: Do you have a rev proxy before tomcat ? Ngnix  httpd haproxy ?

Comment: We are using this one http://haproxy.1wt.eu/ - I also tried direct access without going through the load balancer. With direct access it also failed, but I need to recheck with IT that direct is indeed not mapped in some place...

Comment: I would try to tcpdump http traffic going out of the client and second into the tomcat to see if the param is present in request.

Comment: So it looks like a jersey bug... you might do some jersey debugging and see that request comes out maybe you will pin point the problematic code.

Comment: What do you think about the client code? Is it built OK? `FormDataBodyPart f = new FormDataBodyPart(...);
    FormDataBodyPart f2 = new FormDataBodyPart(...);
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    multiPart.bodyPart(f);
    multiPart.bodyPart(f2);

    //Execute Call
    WebResource wr = resource().path(Url.X);
    wr = wr.queryParam("subjectId", "value_something");
    ClientResponse response = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20098/discussion-between-fatfredyy-and-urir)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servet request lost the params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561505/servet-request-lost-the-params)

Comment: Got the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561505/servet-request-lost-the-params

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem and it turned out that we were allowing multiple threads to access the `HttpServletRequest` object. This is not allowed. It is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Check if request object is valid? 
Also you can try other approaches like reading parameter using request.getParameterMap() or reading Input stream .

Comment: request.getParameterMap() is empty