# Servet request lost the params

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

Question related to [Request parameters are dropped in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560023/request-parameters-are-dropped-in-tomcat)

Well... apparently, even simplest request as below on some servers lost the parameters and some it is OK.

```
@GET
@Path("/get-retrieve")
public String foo(){
    return ""+httpServletRequest.getParameterMap().size();
}
```

so returned value is `0` (zero).

**Update**: the logged request by AccessLogValve contains the parameter

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2012:03:04:58 -0800] "POST /api/get-retrieve?x=y HTTP/1.1" 200 16
```

So, probably the problem is somewhere in the Tomcat throwing out those params...

Comment: This is not how one asks questions on StackOverflow. Post code and one broken configuration, so we can run it and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This is the whole code I have, it's a simple GET that lost the params. I am looking for a help and a direction, not just for direct solution.

Comment: Are you blind or what? The log says `POST /api/get-retrieve HTTP/1.1`. You even downvoted my answer. You keep sending a POST to a method annotated with `@GET` and ask why it's not working...

Comment: The log 'POST' is copy-paste mistake. IT IS 'GET'

Comment: I never heard of pasting replacements. Why don't you use `@QueryParam` in the `foo()` signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this once, after a long investigation it turned out the problem was in the definition of the Connector in Tomcat's server.xml :

`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxHttpHeaderSize="9000" maxParameterCount="100" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Look at the definition of "maxParameterCount", in our case it was set to 0 which caused all request parameters to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

be sure u not pass the httpServletRequest to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and it turned out that we were allowing multiple threads to access the `HttpServletRequest` object. This is not allowed. It is not thread safe.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code posted in the linked question

```
wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, multipart);
```

the problem may be that you annotate your method with `@GET`, but actually your client issues a `POST`. Maybe some implementation of JAX-RS still route the request to your method but fail to extract parameters because of method mismatching. The algorithm is indeed very different once you compare what a GET looks like:

```
GET /path/to/resource?id=foobar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

and a POST:

```
POST /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=A9zfsdf0x;9ad

--A9zfsdf0x;9ad
content-disposition: form-data; name="id"

foobar
```

So, when you design your RESTful API, you should carefully choose the method, and use it both on the client and on the server.

Comment: Hi, in the linked question the POST goes to POST. In this small example it is a GET executed by GET...

Comment: So how can one reproduce your problem? It's very unlikely that the entire world runs on JavaEE and you have spotted a bug regarding GET parsing...

Comment: I am not sure, I am looking for help here. There are 3 hosts in my office having the problem and 3 others are OK...